# How to add to column type a "delete on cascade" in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I built a big database with many tables. After that I forgat to add "delete on cascade". How do I add the "delete on casade" on the specific columns I want ?

For example:

```
create table Users
(
   ID char(9) primary key check (ID like replicate('[0-9]',9)),
   firstName nvarchar(20) not null,
)
```

And

```
create table Applications
(
   name nvarchar(20) primary key,
   establishDate date not null
)
```

How do I *alter* this table-registered to, so that when I delete an app or users it deletes the rows that has this value?

```
create table RegisteredTo
(
   userID char(9) references Users(ID),
   ApplicationName nvarchar(20) references Applications(name),
   primary key(userID, ApplicationName)
)
```

I tried something like that - but I got errors.

```
alter table RegisteredTo
ALTER COLUMN applicationName references Applications(name) ON DELETE CASCADE 
nvarchar(20)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `FOREIGN CONSTRAINT` and `ON DELETE CASCADE`:

```
ALTER TABLE RegisteredTo 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_RegisteredTo_Users FOREIGN KEY (userID) REFERENCES Users(ID)  ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE RegisteredTo 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_RegisteredTo_Applications FOREIGN KEY (ApplicationName) REFERENCES Applications(name)  ON DELETE CASCADE;
```